# How to produce a print-ready report based on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have a Google Spreadsheet which stores data filtered from another Spreadsheet which in turn is a sorage of Google Froms questionnaire.
I'd like to produce a print-ready report on a filtered data, retreiving certain data columns and laying it out with some titles, decorations etc.
How can I produce such a report using Google tools?

Comment: What would be the desired report be like? A doc, formated cells, an image, a PDF, etc...?

Comment: I expected it to be like doc or pdf papersheet.

Comment: However, I won't mind to have it as a Google Docs - kind of "templated document".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this article it explains pretty well how to: [Google Apps Script to create PDF](http://www.andrewroberts.net/2014/10/google-apps-script-create-pdf/).

It made a predefined template of a Google Docs, copyed it and replaced predefined places with the info in the current line of the Spreadsheet, then convert to PDF. If you don't have a predefined length of elements, you can append new info on the documents with the [body element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body).

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't involve scripts, like some templated document. I'd like to observe the principle of referencing spreadsheet data from a document.

Comment: You _did_ ask a question with the `[google-apps-script]` tag. If you want a non-script answer, Stack Overflow is the wrong forum. Try the [Google Docs Help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/docs-community) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the AutoCrat add-on or Yet Another Mail Merge add-on.